# Caching WCF Method .NET 3.5

Tags: performance, wcf, .net-3.5

I am facing a issue and was wondering if there is any solution to overcome this. The application is a WCF Service developed in .NET 3.5.

Let's say it has 5 functions: A, B, C, D and E.

Now, if I keep calling the function A by using a .NET client, the first time it is called it takes time, but all consecutive calls take much lesser time.

But, if I call the functions in a random order, without each of them being called consecutively, say like A then B then C then A then C then D, all of the function calls take longer time.

Is there any way to overcome this? Like, I mean is the last called function cached or something, so the consecutive calls take lesser time or something like that? Can anything be set in the web.config?